# Fetch all the rows without having a duplicate value in a particular field

Tags: sql

| id | ticket_number | payment_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | paid |
| 2 | 121 | paid |
| 3 | 132 | paid |
| 4 | 100 | refund |
| 5 | 141 | paid |

The above is a sample database table. I want to fetch all id and ticket number without having payment_status == refund. What is the SQL query for this. I want to show only the ticket number without having refund.
output should be:

| id | ticket_number | payment_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 121 | paid |
| 3 | 132 | paid |
| 5 | 141 | paid |

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I don't see the correlation between the title/description of this question and its contents.  If you really want to list all those rows that have been paid, then you'll need a "WHERE payment_status = 'paid' " clause in your query, to select those rows.  But if you're looking to avoid duplicate values in a particular field, please clarify what that really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is you can take the count of each unique ticket_number, and select all the ticket number whose count is less than 2.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ticket_number = t.ticket_number and
                        t2.status = 'refund'
                 );
```